# std::map with structs as values

Tags: c++, containers, std

I have an issue where I need to keep a map of, e.g. vectors, of items, each vector has a corresponding indicator valid for all items for a given key in the map

I guess it could be map of pairs (map<string,pair<vector,bool>>)  but that would e very confusing...

So
I wanted to ask you about code like that:
Would this be considered a correct implementation of the problem, is there any potential issue with this? When I add a new key with myMap["KEY"] nothing can ever break because it autoinitializes my struct? Can anything go wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct ListOfItemsWithIndicator
{
    bool _indicator;
    vector<int> _items;
    
    ListOfItemsWithIndicator(): _indicator(false) {}
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string,ListOfItemsWithIndicator> myMap;
    myMap["ONE"]._items.push_back(1);
    
    std::cout << myMap["ONE"]._items[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes it will initialize your struct. That's the good thing about constructors.

Comment: Have you tried it? Looks OK to me

Comment: Yes I tried it, it works fine, what I am worried about are some potential design problems that I am missing

Comment: Looks ok, except *reading* from the map should use `.at()` or `.find()`, never `[]`. The latter inserts missing elements, which is not what you want when reading.

Comment: `operator[]` of a `std::map` will construct the object (using default constructor) if an item with that key does not already exist.

Comment: _Can anything go wrong here?_ This is C++.  Of _course_ something can go wrong!